# Capybara returns Argument error when attach the file

Tags: ruby, capybara, browser-automation

I am working on browser automation and trying to attach the file using the Capybara software. I have a button by clicking which my script should start to upload the file.
It works already in one place on the same website for me, so I am trying to implement it again.

The way I do it:

```
$private_key_path = '/Users/user1/Desktop/my_file.zip'

upload_generated_zip_btn = browser.all(:element, 'material-button', text: 'Upload generated ZIP')

browser.attach_file($private_key_path) do
  upload_generated_zip_btn[0].click
end
```

But in fact my script just clicks the button, then appears the pop-up where I can manually choose the file. After several seconds the script fails with the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Capybara was unable to determine the file input you're attaching to
```

I looked at the docs, at original code but didn't understand the issue. The manual upload of the same files works. Tried to change the locator - no results.

The screenshot of the button code:

[image]

Source Code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the block version of attach_file Capybara attaches a listener for clicks on `<input type="file">` elements and uses that to determine which input you want a file attached to.  Since it's not finding it either it's not triggering the click, or the way your code is structured is hiding the click from Capybara. First I'd ask why you're using `all` and the `element` selector type to find the button and instead suggest (assuming browser is the Capybara session??)

```
browser.attach_file($private_key_path) do
  browser.find('material-button', text: 'Upload generated ZIP').click
end
```

It's tough to say if that's correct because you don't actually show the HTML for a button with that text in your question though. If that still doesn't work then you're going to need to actually locate the file input element and use the non-block version of attach_file.  Something like

```
attach_file($private_key_path, make_visible: true)
```

or by first finding the file input yourself

```
browser.find('input[type="file"]', visible: false).attach_file($private_key_path, make_visible: true)
```

Again it's hard to say for sure since your HTML doesn't appear to actually show the button you're trying to click.

Comment: Hi, I updated the picture of the button HTML. It's not an input field that's why I went with the block version. I use "all" because Capybara finds 2 buttons of this type (I tried different selectors, still 2 buttons). Browser is a Capybara session. Also, when if I put a pry inside the attach_file block and try to click the button manually in the console - it clicks it and opens a dialog where I can choose the file. But it doesn't happen automatically

Comment: If using the inline approach (e.g. your 2nd/3rd example) I am getting Unable to find file field nil that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="material-button" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/........."> (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin - Correct, the `input type="file"` element isn't in the `material-button` element.  From this error I assume you're using `within(...)` to scope this (not shown in your question) - change that to scope to the  `key-file-picker-section` element which does include the input element

Answer (score 0):

Capybara doesn't interact with non-visible elements. So, try to remove hidden attribute and make visible for file selection
Try this:

```
selector = {Selector} # selector for material button
Capybara.current_session.execute_script("document.querySelector('#{selector}').removeAttribute('hidden')")
expect(page).to have_content(file_upload", visible: true)
page.attach_file(
            find('material-button', text: 'Upload generated ZIP'),
            Rails.root.join($private_key_path)
```